# Uncaught ReferenceError: ExtensionSettings is not defined (anonymous function)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm getting an error when loading the Extensions page from chrome:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ExtensionSettings is not defined
   (anonymous function)
```

From the page:

```
chrome://chrome/extensions/
```

This only happens when my extension is active, not when it is disabled (only have at most 1 extension active at all times and it's only this extension).

I should reference that I don't touch in the entire code in the ExtensionSettings variable or object.

The call that's failing reads like this:

```
ExtensionSettings.returnExtensionsData({"developerMode":true,"extensions":[{"allowFileAccess":true,"allow_activity":f...
```

Manifest:

```
{
  "name": "Example Chrome pluggin",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon1.png",
    "default_popup" : "default_popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts" : ["jquery-1.7.2.min.js","background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [ 
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.7.2.min.js","tracker.js"],
      "run_at" : "document_end"
    }   
  ],

  "permissions": ["tabs", "http://www.example.com/", "https://www.example.com/"]
}
```

Comment: last version -- > 20.0.1132.47

Comment: @RobW I'm doing lots of weird stuff like re-writing the XMLHttpRequests prototypes, the keyDown handlers but my guess is that shouldn't affect it. I'll add the manifest there

Comment: Your manifest does not contain any notable items. Besides, Chrome extensions do not have permissions to access or modify `chrome://extensions/`. Have you tried a new profile? `<chrome dir>\chrome.exe --user-data-dir=%tmp%\%random%`

Comment: the error still shows up after I load my extension this is a weird one :p. So far it doesn't have any side-efects, but I don't like leaving errors hanging behind me

Comment: @fmsf I get the same error on my console. An extension installed outside webstore is not updating. Not sure if this error is related or a coincidence.

Comment: Yeah, at the time I wanted to add here the reply but the question got closed. I don't remember exactly what it was though :(